# Getting ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError even with async EventEmitter

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm haunted by this exception and I just don't get what the problem here is. I have a `FormArray` which pushes new items to its controls. These controls are passed down to other child components:

```xml
<mat-card *ngFor="let itemFormGroup of formArray.controls">
  <app-item [formGroup]="itemFormGroup">
  </app-item>
</mat-card>
```

However, I've tried several things but it's just not working. I've now tried to use `EventEmitter<any>(true)` as well as `setTimeout()` etc but I'm am not getting rid of this exception

```
@Output()
addItem = new EventEmitter<any>(true);

onMenuSelected(item) {
  this.addItem.emit({date: this.date, item: item});
}
```

The parent:

```
onAddItem(event) {
  const formArray = <FormArray> this.form.get(event.date);
  formArray.push(this._formBuilder.group(event.item));
}
```

The error:

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ng-valid: true'. Current value: 'ng-valid: false'.

Since I am not setting any property named `valid`, I assume it's the form itself which changes that property during the cycle and breaks things.

How can I avoid this?

---

This is how the `FormArray` gets constructed by the parent. The whole thing is a calendar which is basically a huge `FormGroup` taking the form

```
// pseudo code

form: FormGroup {     // Form of the entire calendar
  date1: FormArray [  // First day in the calendar with a list of items
    item1: FormGroup, // An item in the calendar
    item2: FormGroup
  ],
  date2: FormArray [
  ]
}
```

Here's the logic that builds it:

```
refreshCalendar() {
  const groups = {};

  this.dates.forEach(d => {
    groups[d] = this._formBuilder.array([]);
  });

  if (Object.keys(groups).length > 0) {
    this.form = this._formBuilder.group(groups);
  }

  this.formValueChange$ = this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {this._calendarComponentService.setDirty(this.form.dirty);}, 0);
  });

  // This call is important after resetting in order to propagate the 'dirty' state
  this.form.updateValueAndValidity();

  this.updateItems();
}

updateItems() {
  if (Object.keys(this.items).length > 0) {
    for (const k of Object.keys(this.items)) {
      const formArray = <FormArray> this.form.get(k);
      if (formArray == null) {
        continue;
      }
      for (const item of this.items[k]) {
        formArray.push(this._formBuilder.group(item));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you create demo of the problem in stackblitz?

Comment: Hard to tell without more code. Consider to add the relevant sections of your code, which IMO are any sections of the child component that interact with the passed control + the generation of the `FormArray`

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Vinaayakh's answer actually did the trick. I can even remove the `EventEmitter` and run this change in the child component (which is what surprises me a but tbh) but well I will go for it for the sake of progress XD

Comment: Not really a good solution though, calling `detectChanges` will run change detection on the whole component tree in a sync way, so it will degrade the perf of your app. Just noticed, is there any reason why you are giving `true` to the `EventEmitter` constructor?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I totally agree - I don't like calling `detectChanges` for a few reasons too. Setting `true` to `EventEmitter` was just me trying to skip a beat and then push a new element to the list. At this point I believe that it won't matter. What triggers this error is probably the `push()` to the `FormArray` which then triggers the UI change, but probably sets internally it's `valid` member from `true` to `false` that that's what might throw the exception. But that's just a guess now.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I'd definitely prefer another solution over the accepted one. I can still add the part where `FormArray` gets constructed in the parent.

Comment: I suppose that the `formArray` variable in the uppermost template refers to the mapped value of a key inside of the `form` member, right? IMO if you want anyone in SO to give some further insight, you will have to provide a minimal reproduction of your issue.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I'll try to prepare one later on but for now I just need it to work. :)

Comment: how about injecting NgZone and pushing the new item into the Forms array inside ngZone.run() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try injecting [ChangeDetectionRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) and call detectChanges() after you insert the new item.

Comment: I don't really like this solution but it actually works. I now wonder if I even need the  `EventEmitter` and can update this directly in the child component.

Comment: glad to hear it helped. I will Update the answer if I find a better solution.

Comment: I'm just not a big fan of things like `setTimeout` and `detectChanges()` because I think they always suggest to me that I'm doing it not like I'm supposed to.. ^^